# Bare minimum to send email in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, smtp

I have IIS installed, smtp role/feature activated, and hosting a web application. Do I need to configure IIS for SMTP or can I just create an SmtpClient with the proper configuration in the code? As in, do I have to fill this out

[image]

or would this work?

[image]

Also, when creating a MailMessage does the From address have to be a valid address or could I make it a "spoofed" address like "thisaddressisntreal@mycompany.com"?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to specify anithing in IIS to use the `SmtpClient` object in `C#`.

You only need to fill in your host information, username and password and it should work right of the bat unless the port is blocked in your firewall.

If your email provider is an Exchange server then i know you can "spoof" the `from` email if the server allows it. It is an option in Exchange itself that let pass or not outgoing email with invalid return address. You can ask your IT to see if it's enabled or not.

Other email provider might offer such feature but those are per case basis. You should contact the company that provide the service and they will be able to tell you if you can or not.

Comment: if port 25 is blocked try port 587